# How to handle JSON data in angularJs?

Tags: json, angularjs

In my Controller call function like

```
Auth.register(credentials, config).then(function(registeredUser) {
        console.log(registeredUser);         
    }, function(error) {
        // Registration failed...
        console.log(error);

    });
```

It returns  the JSON data  response like

```
 {"errors":{"email":["has already been taken"]}}
```

On console the data object like

```
data    
Object { errors={...}}
errors  
Object { email=[1]}
email   
["has already been taken"]
0   
"has already been taken"
```

But how to access/get email error message to alert..?

Comment: Try `data.errors.email[0]`

Comment: Sorry it's not working ...

Comment: Why? http://jsfiddle.net/9b7xt12r/

Comment: Error: data is not defined

Comment: ´data´ is a example, try `console.log(error.errors.email[0])`

Comment: I also tried error.errors.email[0] it also shows TypeError: error.errors is undefined

Comment: error is displayed as a string or object?, see my answer.

Comment: TypeError: error.errors is undefined
console.log(error.errors.email[0]);

Answer (score 1):

It's working using like this

```
console.log(error.data.errors.email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Auth.register(credentials, config).then(function(registeredUser){

    console.log(registeredUser);     

}, function(error) {
    // Registration failed...

    try{
        error = JSON.parse(error)
    }catch(e){}

    console.log(error.errors.email[0]);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
console.log(error.errors.email[0]);
```